# Overriding the template of FOS Message Bundle

Tags: php, css, symfony

I'm using FOS MessageBundle for the first time, and it goes well after I finished install it into my own project. But the template is the default one, without any CSS style. I want to override the template but I don't know how to do it. 
How can I override a template of FOS MessageBundle? It is the same way with "Overriding FOS UserBundle Template"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is framework-wide feature when it comes to overriding templates.

Just create the file

```
/app/Resources/FOSMessageBundle/views/.../template-you-want-to-override.html.twig
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you'll need to **clear the cache** before new file clicks in.